# How do I add user input in the middle of a URL in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working on an Android program for a bit and I'm going crazy here... I'm trying to let the user enter a few numbers that would be put into the middle of a URL.
I need the code to read from a text box.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public void browser(View view) 
{
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.website.com/(',R.id.isbn'));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Doing this just adds the (',R.id.isbn')); to the URL.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer Anand posted is a simple solution to your problem. If you want the ISBN to be in the middle of the URL, you can just concatenate it like this:

```
EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.isbn);  
String isbn = t.getText().toString();
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.website.com/" + isbn + "/more-text-here"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Read more about concatenating strings here:

http://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured it was something simple I was forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way.

```
EditText t= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isbn);  
String st= t.getText().toString();
Uri.parse("http://www.website.com/"+st);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The issue I'm having is I need the isbn to be in the middle of the url. I've searched high and low to figure out how to break up the URL and put the isbn in. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are talking about Android EditText field, you could read it's value using `editText.getText().toString()`. This is an example on how to use it in your application:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //... init code cutted

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText editText   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isbn);

    button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String isbnText = editText.getText().toString());
                // other code to open the new activity
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: You've set the listener on the `EditText` instead of the `Button`

Comment: Thank you Titus, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Let your URL be like String url ="http://www.website.com/%1s/somevalue/%2s/etc+%3s";

Call String.format(url,1,2,3);

Hope this will solve your problem